# Kibana dashboard query

Tags: filter, dashboard, kibana

I have a few queries which give me some groups of results. I want to add a new query which displays the rest of the results that were not covered by the previous queries.

Is it possible to have a query something like 'All results minus results from other queries'? I want to avoid adding a filter as that would mean that I have to write the same information in both the query and the filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have 2 queries

```
+type:access-log status:200
+type:access-log status:304
```

The query for the rest is

```
+type:access-log NOT status:200  NOT status:304
```

The syntax is Lucene search syntax, documented [here](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html)

Comment: Thanks, I guess this is the only solution available for now; I was hoping that I won't have to rewrite all queries in the body of the new query (NOT status:200  NOT status:304), because I have 50+ queries and it becomes a bit error-prone